# How to resolve SQL SUM not working correctly?

Tags: sql

I have an SQL data table called sales that records product, quantity sold, unit price, and the date of the sale. I would like to create a view with monthly sales for chairs from 2000-2010. That is, for every unique month and year pair I would like to sum up quantity * unit_price where the product = "CHAIR". My attempt is the following:

```
CREATE VIEW MONTHLY_SALES(product, monthly_sales, month, year) AS (
SELECT product, SUM(quantity * unit_price) AS monthly_sales,
           TO_CHAR(sale_date, 'Month') AS month, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sale_date) AS year
FROM sales
WHERE sale_date BETWEEN '2000-01-01' AND '2010-12-31' AND product = 'CHAIR'
GROUP BY quantity, unit_price, article, sale_date);
    
SELECT *
FROM MONTHLY_SALES;
```

I would expect to sum over the same month and year and get something like:

```
product | monthly_sales | month | year
Chair     100             January 2001
Chair     110             February 2001
Chair     120             March    2001
Chair     300             April    2001
```

But I'm seeing different monthly_sales for the same month-year pairs so I don't know why the SUM isn't working. Any assistance to fix this would be much appreciated.

===============================================================

Sample Data:

```
product | quantity | unit_price | sales_date
Chair     1             40        2001-01-01
Chair     3             40        2001-01-02
Chair     4             40        2001-02-01
Chair     1             40        2001-02-05
```

Expected Output:

```
product | monthly_sales | month   | year
Chair     160             January   2001
Chair     200             February  2001
```

Comment: Please, tag the right sql vendor. And have you tried `WHRE sale_date >= '2000-01-01' and sale_date <= '2010-12-31'`

Comment: Please post sample data and expected results - without that, we're guessing. 
I'm guessing that it's because your group by is wrong - you're not grouping by product, month and year.
What you're asking is "every time you see a change in any of quantity, price, article (whatever that is) and date, perform the sum". 
Most RDBMS engines will reject the query for that reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT product, SUM(quantity * unit_price) AS monthly_sales,
           EXTRACT(MONTH from sales_date) AS month, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sales_date) AS year
FROM sales
WHERE sales_date BETWEEN '2000-01-01' AND '2010-12-31' AND product = 'CHAIR'
group by product, year, month
```

I've created a [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4tqZfeFcDi3LGm17FKauSN/0)

Your group by is wrong - you're not grouping by product, month and year. What you're asking is "every time you see a change in any of quantity, price, article (whatever that is) and date, perform the sum". That will create lots of duplicates (if you have two sales in a given year/month combination, your group by says "create a new row because you've seen a change in sales date).

Comment: This will work in MySQL, but i.e. Oracle will not accept aliases in the group by like this

Answer (score 1):

You are grouping by the sales date, instead of the month and year of the sale. You will get one record per sales_date instead of one record per month. This example will work in your case:

```
CREATE VIEW MONTHLY_SALES(product, monthly_sales, month, year) AS (
SELECT product, SUM(quantity * unit_price) AS monthly_sales,
           TO_CHAR(sale_date, 'Month') AS month, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sale_date) AS year
FROM sales
WHERE sale_date BETWEEN '2000-01-01' AND '2010-12-31' AND product = 'CHAIR'
GROUP BY article, TO_CHAR(sale_date, 'Month'), EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sale_date));
    
SELECT *
FROM MONTHLY_SALES
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried this result and it certainly gave me fewer values but there are still duplicate values. Is there any other way to order the GROUP BY to make the SUM work as required?

Comment: Ah yes, you shouldn't group by `unit_price` (as you are aggregating that). I changed the answer.

Comment: Thanks very much! In that case, quantity should also be removed. Otherwise, this answer works perfectly. Thanks again!

Comment: Right you are, wasn't paying enough attention there! changed it in the answer.